# relocation error: symbol pthread_getattr_np, version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libpthread.so.0 with link time reference

Tags: c, elf, glibc

I would like to use [dust](https://github.com/bootandy/dust) for my remote server (without root permission). I unzipped the executable from [dust release](https://github.com/bootandy/dust/releases/tag/v0.8.1). But when I ran it throwed

```
dust: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by dust)
```

After some googling, I figured this was caused by system-installed `glibc` version being too low. So I installed `gcc 11.3.0` and `glibc 2.35` from the source. Since I do not have root permission, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/851229#851229) I learned to use [patchelf](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf) to inject the `glibc` path:

```
patchelf --set-rpath /path/to/glibc/lib dust
```

I thought it would solve every issue but no, there was again one more issue:

```
dust: relocation error: dust: symbol pthread_getattr_np, version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libpthread.so.0 with link time reference
```

But I do have a `libpthread.so.0` in `/path/to/glibc/lib`.

I couldn't find any useful information online, except [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938200/glibc-2-2-5-not-defined-in-file-libpthread-so-0-with-link-time-reference). Yet I couldn't find this page very useful.

I'm using Cent OS 7.

If anyone has any clue, I would highly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from this question I learned to use patchelf to inject the glibc path

You have done ½ of the job you need to do.

In addition to setting `RPATH`, you *also* need to set the interpreter (as the referenced answer explains). `patchelf --set-interpreter /path/to/glibc/lib/ld-linux.so.2 dust` should do.